# Wildfly 9 killing my oracle DB

Tags: oracle, wildfly

I am on window 7, oracle 11.2 wildfly 9.0.2, cisco VPN

I can start my wildfly deployment lovely and it works. i close it down using the correct command and then it has killed my DB. The only way i have found to actually get it running again, is to reboot my PC.

After I restart the DB and the TNS service I get this error:

```
An error was encountered performing the requested operation:

Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12505, TNS:listener does not currently know of SID given in connect descriptor


Vendor code 12505
```

I don't know what other information you might need

from my standalone.xml

```
<concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
```

so next time i start wildfly I get this:

```
11:22:42,619 WARN  [org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.strategy.OnePool] (JCA PoolFiller) IJ000610: Unable to fill pool: javax.r
esource.ResourceException: IJ031084: Unable to create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:496)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:410)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.createConnectionEventListener(Semaphor
eArrayListManagedConnectionPool.java:1289) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.2.5.Final.jar:1.2.5.Final]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnectionPool.fillTo(SemaphoreArrayListManagedConnec
tionPool.java:1126) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.2.5.Final.jar:1.2.5.Final]
        at org.jboss.jca.core.connectionmanager.pool.mcp.PoolFiller.run(PoolFiller.java:97) [ironjacamar-core-impl-1.2.5.Final.jar:1.2.
5.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_152]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Listener refused the connection with the following error:
ORA-12519, TNS:no appropriate service handler found

        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:489)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.<init>(PhysicalConnection.java:553)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.<init>(T4CConnection.java:254)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:528)
        at oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource.getPhysicalConnection(OracleDataSource.java:280)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getPooledConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:472)
        at oracle.jdbc.xa.client.OracleXADataSource.getXAConnection(OracleXADataSource.java:156)
```

this is from the listener log for the second run: it can find connections to begin with.

```
Sat Jan 13 11:54:31 2018
13-JAN-2018 11:54:31 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53595)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53600)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53603)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53604)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53605)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53606)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53607)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53608)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53609)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:32 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53610)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:33 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53611)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:33 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53612)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:33 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53613)) * establish * XE * 0
13-JAN-2018 11:54:34 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53614)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:34 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53615)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:34 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53616)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
Sat Jan 13 11:54:52 2018
13-JAN-2018 11:54:52 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53618)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:52 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53619)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:53 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53620)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:53 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53621)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:58 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53622)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
13-JAN-2018 11:54:58 * (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=XE)(CID=(PROGRAM=JDBC Thin Client)(HOST=__jdbc__)(USER=WGibbons))) * (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=127.0.0.1)(PORT=53623)) * establish * XE * 12519
TNS-12519: TNS:no appropriate service handler found
```

Edit to add more info.

Comment: how you shutdown wildfly server instance ? using CLI command or using kill -15 ?  I dont think shutting down wildfly instance will kill DB instance as well ? Have you check logs from DB end ?

Comment: I am using jboss-cli.bat --command close (this won't be syntax perfect as i am answering from my home ipad not work machine).. and stupid idiot I haven't checked any logs.

Comment: ok correct answer jboss-cli.bat --connect command=:shutdown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add and extra section to my listener.ora file
I had to add this, as the first entry in the SID_LIST.

I do not know why it helped but eventually somebody else in the office recognised my symptoms.

```
(SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = XE)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
    )
```